# How to prevent an instance deletion from ASG while executing userdata in instance, AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2

LC:

- Configured for creating ubuntu instance.
- Added userdata for installing tomcat7.

ASG:

- Used same configuration for creating ASG group with single instance.
- Attached ELB for load balancing between instance.
- ELB health check:

  ```
   --------------------
      Ping Target HTTP:8080/
      Timeout 5 seconds
      Interval    30 seconds
      Unhealthy threshold 5
      Healthy threshold   5
  ```

Issue: The ASG will declare the instance is unhealthy if the userdata take time to configure the instance beyond the interval of healthcheck. So I need to disabled the ELB healthcheck while configuring instance. Once its done, healthcheck should be enabled.

is there any possibility to control this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a health check grace period setting which defaults to 5 minutes (300s).  You did not specify how you created the autoscaling group, but, for example, with the AWS CLI, you'd call it as `aws autoscaling create-auto-scaling-group --health-check-grace-period 600 ...` for a 10-minute timeout.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/healthcheck.html

This is, by the way, totally unrelated to the ELB health check, which you should be able to leave alone.  It will just keep checking the instance until it gets a healthy status.  The ELB health check does not affect the autoscaling instance lifecycle.